# Audio not playing within thread Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

So i've got an audio file that i'd like to play within a thread, this is where i've left the comment // Tried playing audio here . But the even with the logic to make sure that it only plays once no audio is being played. Instead it seems like it's forcing the application to skip frames instead causing the game to have a few glitches because of the inconsistent frame rate.

Here's the code which i've been using.

```
 while (isRunning) {

            // Go back to the if statement and check if the surface still isn't valid
            if (!mySurfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            // Lock the canvas for editing, make changes and unlock with new changes
            final Canvas canvas = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), pWhite);

            // Create the block to check the answer
            answerObject = new AnswerObject(canvas);
            animalObject.move(canvas, tilt);

            if(answerObject.onCollision(animalObject) != null){


                // Inside of box else is outside of box
                if (answerObject.onCollision(animalObject)) {

                    // If the animal is part of that enviroment
                    if (verifyEnviroment(enviromentObject.getAnimals())){

                        isCorrect = true;

                    } else {

                        isCorrect = false;
                    }

                } else {

                    // If the animal is part of that enviroment
                    if (!verifyEnviroment(enviromentObject.getAnimals())){

                        // Tried playing audio here 
                        isCorrect = true;

                    } else {

                        // Tried playing audio here
                        isCorrect = false;
                    }
                }

                gameActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (isCorrect){


                            scoreObject.setScore(10);

                        } else {

                            healthObject.setHealth(10);
                            healthObject.setHealthImgs(healthObject.getHealth());

                            if (healthObject.getHealth() <= 0){
                                isRunning = false;
                            }

                        }

                        resetGameObjects();
                    }
                });
            }

            mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
```

Comment: does this code run on main thread? and where is the code for audio playing?

Comment: @nandsito Yes it's running on the main thread and where i have left the comment "// Tried playing audio here"

Comment: what audio API are you using? can you show us the code?

Comment: @nandsito I was just using the standard media player API tbh